# Error installing PhoneGap: "Ruby: No such file or directory -- ./droidgap (LoadError)"

Tags: android, cordova

Hello. I've installed the following prerequisites for PhoneGap:

- Java JDK
- Android SDK + ADT Plugin
- Eclipse
- Ruby 1.9.2
- Apache ant

I also added the path to the environment variable. However, when I try to launch with the command:

`ruby ./droidgap "[android_sdk_path]" [name] [package_name] "[www]" "[path]"`

I receive this error:

`Ruby: No such file or directory -- ./droidgap (LoadError)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to run that command in the directory where the `droidgap` script lives.

Answer (score 0):

Or checkout the Eclipse plugin [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android) to avoid the need for droidgap or ruby to get started with PhoneGap on Android